# Using removeClass regex to remove multiple class prefixes

Tags: jquery, regex

The below jQuery searches for and removes any classes containing my prefix `bg-`. It is used on the body to remove any `bg-` prefixed classes i.e `bg-red bg-opacity` and so on.

I'd like to edit this to be able to handle multiple prefixes, i.e `bg-` and `text-`, but am struggling to get this to work.

Is anybody familiar with regex and could help?

```
body.removeClass(function (index, css) {
  return (css.match (/(^|\s)bg-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

Comment: You can use an alternation `\b(?:bg|text)-\S+`

Comment: another question closed half way through a simple answer. `(^|\s)(bg-|ab-|cd-)\S+` allows prefixes `bg-`, `ab-`, `cd-` to demonstrate https://regexr.com/5h67s

Comment: Yes, really frustrating that this has been closed, the other question doesn't resolve this for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In much the same way that the start of your regex searches for the start of the string `(^`) or (`|`) whitespace (`\s`) you can use the same method to search for variations to your prefix

```
(^|\s)(bg-|ab-|cd-)\S+
```

This allows prefixes `bg-`, `ab-`, `cd-` to demonstrate

Live example: https://regexr.com/5h67s

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to break it up to join it again.
Just used replace.

Also instead of adding a space, just return the first parenthesis match.

```
body.removeClass(function (index, css) {
  return css.replace(/(^|\s)(bg|text)-\S+/g), '$1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.prototype.replace()` directly on the `.attr("class")`

```js
$("div").attr("class", (i, cl) => cl.replace(/(^|\s)(bg|text)-\w+/g, ""));

console.log($("div").attr("class")); // "foo bar-ola baz"
```

```html
<div class="foo bg-red bar-ola baz text-blue"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```